# android: how to disable selected and pressed attributes of parent view in listView

Tags: android, listview, parent-child, selected

I have a listView with custom rows containing buttons and I populate the listView with a custom cursorAdapter. I have set a selector for the button to change the background of it when pressed and it works great when I press on the button. The problem is it also works when I press anywhere else on the row.

I tried to set the parent view's .setPressed, .setSelected, .setFocusable, .setFocusableInTouchMode, .setClickable attributes to false but it did not work.

I also tried to set button's .setDuplicateParentStateEnabled to false but it did not help either.

If you can help me I will be grateful,

Thank you in advance

Let me extend my question: I have the rows without the button (which is the TextView with id of "delete_button" in xml code below) first. When I click another button in the view, the delete buttons slide into the rows and the background of the other TextView (id:list_title_text) changes to a constant color (because I don't want it to be clickable anymore)

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/title_rows_relativelayout"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_title_text"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_for_list_rows"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:typeface="normal" />
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/delete_button"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_for_delete_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:textSize="23dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/row_icon_background" 
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp">
    </TextView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to stack over flow. If someone posts an answer that you think is correct, please accept it.

Comment: Thank you! I learned a lot in this forum by just reading the threads and hope to learn a lot more by asking :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by setting the button's setFocusable attribute to true inside my custom ListAdapter (I changed my CursorAdapter to ListAdapter after I wrote the question but I am sure it will work with CursorAdapter too). Now the button background changes only when I click on the button and nothing happens when I click anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Selected, pressed, and activated are explicitly set on children by `ViewGroup.dispatchSetSelected()`, `.dispatchSetPressed()`, and `.dispatchSetActivated()` respectively, regardless of the child's `DUPLICATE_PARENT_STATE` value.  Override those methods in the parent with no-ops to disable these behaviors.

By default, focus and pressed are propagated down to children that are not focusable or clickable, respectively.  In my cases, it was more accurate to mark the appropriate children focusable or clickable, than to `setDuplicateParentState(false)` (which is already the default for a View class).

For me, I found `setDuplicateParentStateEnabled()` to be a red herring, and was able to solve my problems without it.

Comment: this is the correct answer. you should tell the child to be clickable=true in xml so that state do not propagate to it